# How was Munich Captured in WWII?

Tags: world-war-two

How was Munich captured in WWII and how much time did it take?
For example was it on a scale of three days?

This question is because in one of the war-time German films one character hypotizes that Munich can be captured in no more than three days.

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. Could you edit your question to clarify what you've looked into already, complete with links and references, and context if applicable? In particular, please let us know what you find missing or unclear about the Wikipedia entry on the topic, if one exists. This allows those who might want to answer to do so without needing to redo the work you've already done. You might find it helpful to review the site tour and Help Centre and, in particular, How to Ask.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By the time the Allies were set to enter Munich the city was already in shambles. It had been bombed a few times and an [air battle](http://www.wwiiaircraftperformance.org/24april44.html) occured over the city about a year prior. The city was ruined and was basically easily taken. According to this [article](http://www.spiegel.de/international/0,1518,354029,00.html) a US soldier received his orders to enter Munich early in the morning on April 30th, 1945 and by 2PM he was standing on the central square and by the end of the day the city was for the most part captured (There was a pitched battle the next day at the Munich Airport).

For a more in depth view see the section of the article called **"Liberating a semi-deserted city"**

All in all this quote from the article sums up the capture of Munich

> By the end of the day, Robinow and the US soldiers who followed had almost completely taken Munich. Some shots were fired shortly after occupying the city center - and a pitched battle was fought the next day at the Munich airport - but for the most part, Robinow says, the city was left undefended. He finished the day in a villa he and his men liberated along with a full wet bar.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by reference to "pitched battle at Munich airport". Which one? There was the main one in Riem, and the mostly inactive ones in Schleissheim and Oberwiesenfeld. That last combat that took place was around Schleissheim but *before* the taking of the city proper (which I assume new contributor @Bill is referring to). Was there any further fierce combat on May 1 in Riem?

Answer (score -3):

The above answer to this question is incorrect.  In fact, there was a MASSIVE day and a half battle with the best the US Army fielded (20th Armored Division) vs. the last, hardcore Nazi and Wehrmacht anti-tank and artillery soldiers ever fielded by the Third Reich.  700+ Germans were killed and had vowed to die where they stood.  They did.  See the Facebook page dedicated to the 20th Armored Division.

Comment: You appear to have conflated the captures of Nuremberg and Munch.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20th_Armored_Division_(United_States)#Combat_chronicle, the battle described by Bill took place on 28-30 April 1945, in the Neuherberg, a suburb of Munich, near Dachau and the airport.  So I disbelieve Pieter's comment.

Comment: A bit overdramatic. "Massive"? This wasn't exactly Battle for Berlin. Some last SS holdouts, up in the far northern areas of greater Munich - Freimann, Schleissheim - which weren't even Munich proper whereas today the city has grown to their doorsteps). Funnily enough I'm typing this after having just driven through that area an hour ago.